# Terraform optional jsonencode properties

Tags: json, terraform

Okay, take the following snippet of terraform:

```
variable "my_var1" {
  type    = string
  default = null
}
variable "my_var2" {
  type    = string
  default = null
}
output "my_out" {
  value = jsonencode({
    my_attribute1 = var.my_var1
    my_attribute2 = var.my_var2
  })
}
```

I'd like it such that if either `my_var1` & `my_var2` are not specified, they don't appear in `my_out` whatsoever.  (I.e. the output would be `{}`) However instead the output is currently:

```
my_out = {"my_attribute1":null,"my_attribute2":null}
```

Is there a way to do this?  (preferably without having to switch to string interpolation within json text directly)

Answer (score 10):

I was able to get something working leveraging the [for expression](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#for-expressions) along with locals:

```
variable "my_var1" {
  type    = string
  default = null
}

variable "my_var2" {
  type    = string
  default = null
}

locals {
  attributes = {
    my_attribute1 = var.my_var1
    my_attribute2 = var.my_var2
  }
}

output "my_out" {
  value = jsonencode({ for k, v in local.attributes : k => v if v != null })
}
```