# How to properly encode null values inside jsonencode() blocks in Terraform for aws_cloudformation_stack resource?

Tags: terraform, aws-cloudformation, terraform-provider-aws, hcl

There is a [bug in the current version of the  official aws_elasticsearch_domain resource](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/21787) which prevents you from creating new OpenSearch domains (and also changing existing domains).

To circumvent this, I'm working on a module that creates an OpenSearch domain via a [CloudFormation stack](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-opensearchservice-domain.html) using the Terraform `aws_cloudformation_stack` resource.

I want to pass the CloudFormation template via the `jsonencode()` function, so that I can work in HCL instead of JSON.

[Some of the resource parameters are conditional](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-opensearchservice-domain-domainendpointoptions.html), e.g. `CustomEndpoint`. You're only allowed to provide a value if `CustomEndpointEnabled` is set to `true`. Otherwise the parameter has to be omitted completely.

In Terraform one would usually do this via a conditional statement, like this:

```
  DomainEndpointOptions = {
    CustomEndpoint                = var.custom_endpoint_enabled ? var.custom_endpoint : null
    CustomEndpointCertificateArn  = var.custom_endpoint_enabled ? var.custom_endpoint_certificate_arn : null
    CustomEndpointEnabled         = var.custom_endpoint_enabled
    EnforceHTTPS                  = true
    TLSSecurityPolicy             = "Policy-Min-TLS-1-2-2019-07"
  }
```

`jsonencode()` encodes the null value which is the expected behaviour. But the AWS API will throw an error since `null` is an unexpected value.

**So my question is: What is the correct way of omitting conditional values inside `jsonencode()` blocks?**

Comment: Sorry, your question is not clear. Can you provide full example of these conditions and json? Your code that you posted in the question does not use `jsonencode` at all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Terraform optional jsonencode properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63000221/terraform-optional-jsonencode-properties)